# requestAnimationFrame in prototype

Tags: javascript

When I run test.loop() it only executes once instead of at the expected rate. Any ideas what I can do to fix this?

```
"use strict;"

var test = function(options) {
    this.options = options;

    return this;
};

test.prototype = {
    'loop': function() {
        console.log('test');

        if (this !== window) {
            requestAnimationFrame(this.loop);
        }
    }
};

test.loop();
```

Comment: This is unrelated but use `"use strict";` instead of `"use strict;"` or your code won't be parsed in strict mode.

Comment: Uh, if you are already doing such a `this !== window` check, you seem to know about the problem?

Comment: I know it's something to do with the `this` scope but i can't wrap my head around the solution

Comment: I think Bergi overzealously closed as duplicate, because the OP already knew the subtleties of `this` but couldn't figure this specific instance out. Anyway, try this replacement line: `requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));`

Answer (score 0):

`test.loop()` is not a function. `test.prototype.loop` is. And if you do:

```
var x = new test();
x.loop();
```

that will also work. See what you did wrong here? You forgot to use the `new` keyword to create a new object. Your code not only **not works** but it also produces a type error (`undefined is not a function`).

Comment: Typed up my code snippet wrong, I am in fact using an instance of test and running the loop method of this instance. The problem of it not doing requestAnimationFrame still exists

Comment: @Adam I actually was about to point out the problem, but it definitely clashes with what the OP said - the loop "executes only once". So it's something else...